# Excel VBA - run a macro residing in workbook A to affect workbook B. B's name is a wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to use filter in workbook B, with clipboard content from workbook A. Workbook B name is a wildcard and macro needs to be run from workbook A.  So far I have:

```
Sub SwitchAndFilter()
'

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
   If wb.Name Like "*ABC_*" Then wb.Activate:
   With ActiveWorkbook
'code here just getting run onto workbook A, plus don't know how to pass clipboard contents to a filter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$501").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="12345" ' this should be clipboard contents from Workbook A
   End With
    Exit Sub
Next wb

'if code gets here, it isn't already open...
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 1** Getting "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" on line:

```
.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1").Paste
```

per advice below "should get the filter criteria from the range, not the clipboard" with that code I'm trying first to paste clipboard into range on wbB, and then refer to that range to filter.  Full code I have now is:

```
Sub SwitchAndFilter3()
    Dim wbA As ThisWorkbook
    Dim wbB As Workbook

    Set wbA = ThisWorkbook

    For Each wbB In Application.Workbooks
        If wbB.Name Like "*ABC_*" And wbA.Name <> wbB.Name Then

            'Your with should reference the context of your for, i.e. wbB, not ActiveWorkbook.
            With wbB

                'You should really try to avoid Activesheet
                'Also, you should get the filter criteria from the range, not the clipboard.
                '
                .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1").Paste
                .ScrollColumn = 2
                '
                .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$W$501").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1").Value

                'If you need wbB to be active:
                .Activate

            End With

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wbB
```

**COPY SUB FOR @ValonMiller** 9.26.18 In response to request in comment below

```
Sub CopyFirstOne()
Dim position As Integer
Dim substring As String
position = InStr(ActiveCell, " ")
If (position > 0) Then
    substring = Left(ActiveCell, position - 1)

    Dim MyText As DataObject
    Set MyText = New DataObject

    On Error Resume Next
    MyText.setText substring
    MyText.PutInClipboard

End If
'below macro works on it's own, but Calling from here crashes XL for a bit and gives error on PasteSpecial
'Call SwitchAndFilterWorks
End Sub
```

**10.8.18 Update**

```
Sub ListFiles_A3_Works()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

    Application.Goto Reference:="Body"
    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("B6").Select

objFolderName = Range("A3").Value

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFolderName)
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("A3").Value)
i = 5
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'print file name
Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
'print file path
'Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
i = i + 1
Next objFile
    Range("B6").Select
    Range("A6").Select
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Selection.Row
Call CopyFirstOne
End Sub
```

Comment: Is Workbook A `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: Also, is the filter criteria being copied from a range(i.e. a cell)? Which cell and on which sheet?

Comment: Why are you activating a worksheet, and using `ActiveWorkbook` within a `For each wb` loop? Just use `If wb.Name like "whatever" Then // wb.Sheets("whateverSheet").Range([whatever])...`?  Also, please format the code properly, the `:` at the end of the `If` statement is incorrect and won't work.  Where's the `End If`? You know you're exiting the sub after the first `Wb` right?

Comment: @Alex the criteria should be `Criteria1:=.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1").Value`. exclude wbB because it is already the context within the `With`. Regarding the error, make sure that you actually have a sheet name "Sheet1", if that is not actually the name of the sheet then you need to update that in the code. The other potential problem is the copy source, what is being copied and from where? if its being copied from outside of excel, then what you have might work, if its supported for pasting by Excel. If you're trying to copy something from wbA, then I don't see the copy happening here.

Comment: @ValonMiller - by the time I am running this Sub, copying already took place from wbA.  Per your note above: I have excluded wbB & renamed all "Sheet1" references in wbB to actual sheet name, but keep getting "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" on that same line...

Comment: @Alex try `.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AA1").PasteSpecial`. Also, for the scroll column to work you will need to add a line `.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` above that and update the scroll line to `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2`. I will update the code in my answer to include this.

Comment: @Alex Another thing to check if you still get the subscript error, make sure cut copy mode is active when you debug the error. Add `Application.CutCopyMode` to the watch window.

Comment: @ValonMiller - can you clarify your last comment? I know debug means clicking on that button when error comes up. Not sure how to "Add Application.CutCopyMode to the watch window" Maybe that will help.  I am able to run this macro on it's own, after another macro had extracted portion of cell content into Clipboard, but when I Call this macro from that macro, Excel crashed for a bit then gives "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed"

Comment: @Alex View > Watch Window. Right Click in the watch window to add a watch and add Application.CutCopyMode. Then you can monitor the status of the cut copy mode in the watch window, it needs to be 1 when the code hits the paste - otherwise, it means there is nothing currently copied, i.e. there is no source which would throw subscript out of range. For more info on watch and screen shots try this page: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/add_watch2016.php

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where the copy is occurring?

Comment: @ValonMiller - I put COPY SUB in original post

Comment: I did some testing on the clipboard method you are trying to implement, and was able to get it to work with PasteSpecial; Paste did not work at all. However my recommendation now is to abandon the copy/paste as unnecessary overhead. You are already determining the string that you want to filter on, just pass that to the filter Sub directly. There is no need to bring copy/paste into the workflow. I have updated my answer below with revised code for both procedures.

Comment: Also, `On Error Resume Next` should be avoided, you might be getting an error on the copy that you never see, which could be causing the downstream subscript out of range error (because there is nothing in the clipboard).

Comment: @ValonMiller - Feels like we are almost there - it does not give any errors; on wbB filter is activated but it excludes everything (I made sure it's not hidden by being scrolled out of visible), even though I made sure string does exist in that column, result is not showing (oddly though, when I clear filter it is exactly the lines with string result that remain highlighted - I feature I have in wbB for filtered column), so it's almost as though it does recognize the strings, just does not display them when filtered on...

Comment: @ValonMiller - **V2.0** - seeing how two macros work separately, but we can't seem to tie them to work from one click - I've assigned a cell J1 on wbA SelectionChange to trigger second macro - SwitchAndFilterWorks. **Test results:** when copy macro is run, then J1 is clicked **manually** it does the PasteSpecial and runs the filter perfectly displaying results, BUT adding a code at end of first macro to select J1, gives brief crash then "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed" on .Range("AA1").PasteSpecial

Comment: @Alex I'm having difficulty following what your describing, but it sounds like you are still tying to implement a copy/paste - I don't understand why. Take a look at my revised answer below. If that is not resolving the problem, or you cannot work through to a solution from that starting point, then there is something missing from what I can see about the problem, i.e. data, or requirements that have not been disclosed. I cannot assist further unless there is new information about the root problem. I'm starting to think this is an XY problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @ValonMiller -Maybe you've missed first of my two latest comments? Two together may help "Feels like we are almost there - it does not give any errors; on wbB filter is activated but it excludes everything (I made sure it's not hidden by being scrolled out of visible), even though I made sure string does exist in that column, result is not showing (oddly though, when I clear filter it is exactly the lines with string result that remain highlighted - I feature I have in wbB for filtered column), so it's almost as though it does recognize the strings, just does not display them when filtered on"

Comment: One thing that's happening in CopyFirstOne() is there is not else. so if `" "` is not found then its filtering on = "". Maybe try adding `Else substring = Activecell.Value`. My answer has been updated to include this.

Comment: `substring = ""` might also be why you are getting the error, maybe it sees the clipboard as empty when that happens?

Comment: Oh, actually, due to `If (position > 0) Then` nothing is copied if the ActiveCell.value does not contain a `" "`, which means there is nothing to paste when you get to the other sub. This is still the same solution, you need to capture the `Else` use case in your If on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated 9/26 based on discussion above]**

Make sure you update the line `With wbB.Sheets("Sheet1")` with the correct sheet name.

```
Sub CopyFirstOne()
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim substring As String

    position = InStr(ActiveCell, " ")

    If (position > 0) Then
        substring = Left(ActiveCell, position - 1)
    Else
        substring = ActiveCell.Value
    End If

    'Pass the filter string directly
    Call SwitchAndFilter(substring)
End Sub

Sub SwitchAndFilter(fitlerValue As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*ABC_*" And ThisWorkbook.Name <> wb.Name Then

            'Changed with to target Sheet, instead of Workbook
            With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                .Range("$A$1:$W$501").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=fitlerValue

                'Optional
                .Activate

            End With

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wb

    'if code gets here, it isn't already open...

End Sub
```

Comment: "Run-time error'438': Object doesn't support this property or method" on line `If wbB.Name Like "*ABC_*" And wbA <> wbB Then`

Comment: @Alex it's because you can't explicitly compare `workbook` objects. Instead, change it to something like `And wbA.FullName <> wbB.FullName Then`

Comment: @Valon - I could perhaps get away with keeping wbA always the same name, but wbB would always vary - that's why I stated in my question "Workbook B name is a wildcard"...

Comment: @Alex wbA is not changing, it is always referring to `ThisWorkbook`. wbB is the current workbook in the context of your for loop. The comparison of the name is being evaluated so that the `IF` block is acting upon all workbooks except itself.

Comment: @ValonMiller - can you take a look at my **UPDATE 1** in original question at top of this thread - I have posted the full code I am running now, explanation and line of code that gives error... (Also in my previous comment, just above I replied to you, not having noticed that comment I was replying to was from Marcucciboy2 and not from you)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution, but to address what I believe to be the root cause of your copy/paste issue, try this:

```
Sub CopyFirstOne()
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim substring As String
    Dim MyText As DataObject

    Set MyText = New DataObject

    position = InStr(ActiveCell, " ")

    If (position > 0) Then
        substring = Left(ActiveCell, position - 1)
    Else
        substring = ActiveCell.Value
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    MyText.setText substring
    MyText.PutInClipboard

    Call SwitchAndFilterWorks
End Sub
```

Comment: File names I work with always have at least one space.  When trying this version of CopyFirstOne() performance is even worst, it's not even listing the files from the directory and after a freeze gives "Run-time error '76': Path not found" on line Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objFolderName) in Sub ListFiles_A3_Works() I will paste that Sub with 10.8.18 Update in my original post